# Snap.svg transform not working - possible issue with element selection?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

```js
function base_axes() {
 var s = Snap("#base_axes");
 var dim = 0.1*window.innerWidth;
 var x_line = s.line(0, dim, 0, dim);
 x_line.attr("stroke", "#5e0734");
 x_line.attr("stroke-width", "5px");
 x_line.animate({
  x2: window.innerWidth
 }, 1000, mina.easein);
 var y_line = s.line(dim, 0, dim, 0);
 y_line.attr("stroke", "#5e0734");
 y_line.attr("stroke-width", "5px");
 y_line.animate({
  y2: window.innerHeight
 }, 1000, mina.easein);
 Snap.load('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Tux.svg', function(data) {
  var logo = s.append(data);
  var bbox = logo.getBBox();
  var scale_factor = dim/bbox.height;
  var transform_string = "s" + scale_factor + "," + scale_factor;
  logo.transform(transform_string);
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/snap.svg.js"></script>
<body onload="base_axes()">

  <svg id="base_axes" height="100%" width="100%"></svg>
```

I'm using this to load an svg into another svg and then transform it:

```
<svg id="base" height="100%" width="100%"></svg>
```

JS:

```
var s = Snap("#base");
var dim = 1;
    Snap.load('img.svg', function(data) {
            var logo = s.append(data);
            var bbox = logo.getBBox();
            console.log(bbox);
            var scale_factor = dim/bbox.height;
            var transform_string = "'s" + scale_factor + "," + scale_factor + "'";
            logo.transform(transform_string);
        });
```

But nothing happens. In an effort to troubleshoot, I replaced the bottom line with `logo.transform('s0.1,0.1')`, and that failed too. Is there something wrong with the creation of `logo`?

To clarify - the first svg, #id, is selected correctly, the new svg (logo) is correctly appended to it, and bbox is calculated correctly, but the final transform does nothing. The transform string looks correct, evaluating to `s0.03,0.03`, but the final line `logo.transform(transform_string)` does nothing.

Comment: I think we're going to need a [mcve]. What is img.svg, what element has id="id" etc

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried to make a fiddle, but struggled due to the need to include my own local file, as well as the fact the fiddle.js does not have Snap.svg builtin. I tried importing it, but it refused.
In any case, I've added more detail to the question which should clarify things!

Comment: you could make img.svg into a data url so it wouldn't be a local file. You can include other javascript in Stack Snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line, but I can't be sure without seeing it in a test example...

```
var logo = s.append(data);
```

If you look at the docs [here](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.append), it says it returns the parent element. So you are saying 'logo = the svg element'.

The svg element doesn't allow transforms (in some browsers, see Roberts comment below).

So you either want to select for example a 'g' element in the svg logo by selecting it (eg s.select('#logo') or Snap('#logo'), but we haven't seen that to know if it exists), or append the svg logo to a 'g' element thats inside your svg element eg

```
<svg id="base" height="100%" width="100%"><g id="logo"></g></svg>
```

then you can apply the transform to that, rather than the svg, eg

```
var logo = Snap('#logo').append(data)
```

You also need to remove the quotes in your transform string. I.e

```
var transform_string = "s" + scale_factor + "," + scale_factor;
```

Comment: transforms are supported on the svg element in SVG 2. Firefox supports this part of SVG 2.

Comment: I've added a snippet - I did try what you suggested, but it didn't work - it could not find do ` var logo = Snap('#logo').append(data)` as it claimed that Snap('#logo') was null.

Comment: Get rid of the extra quotes as well, so use var transform_string = "s" + scale_factor + "," + scale_factor;